# Error missing {

Tags: math-mode, missing

Im getting this error in the heading of a table and two formulas, previously I had typped other formulas without errors. 
This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mutavel}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Коэффициента профильного сопротивления каждого участка крыла}
    \label{tab:c_f_at_diff_positions_l/2}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        № участки & $\bar_{x_t}$   & Re, e$^7$ & \eta_C    & C_F, e$^{-3}$ & 2C_F$\bar_S$, e$^{-4}$   \\ \hline
        1         & 0,0756       & 4,4683    & 1,3807    & 2,3886        & 2,8173                 \\ \hline
        2         & 0,0868       & 5,8915    & 1,3768    & 2,4376        & 7,2592                 \\ \hline
        3         & 0,1018       & 3,3214    & 1,3719    & 2,4956        & 6,3388                 \\ \hline
        4         & 0,1148       & 2,9435    & 1,3694    & 2,3388        & 4,9115                 \\ \hline
        5         & 0,1461       & 2,3137    & 1,3636    & 2,3676        & 5,6728                 \\ \hline
        6         & 0,1666       & 2,0286    & 1,3598    & 2,3767        & 4,9863                 \\ \hline
        7         & 0,1938       & 1,7436    & 1,3547    & 2,3796        & 4,2880                 \\ \hline
        8         & 0,2317       & 1,4585    & 1,3399    & 2,3700        & 3,5692                 \\ \hline
        9         & 0,2897       & 1,1668    & 1,3148    & 2,3322        & 2,8173                 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Суммарный коэффициент трения крыла определится по формуле:

\begin{equation}
    C_\textup{xa F кр}=2C_\textup{F кр}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (2C_\textup{F j}\bar_{S_j}),
    \label{eq:sum_c_f_wing}
\end{equation}
т.о. 
\begin{equation*}
    C_\textup{xa F кр}=2C_\textup{F кр}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (2C_\textup{F j}\bar_{S_j})=(2,8173+7,2592+6,3388+4,9115+5,6728+4,9863+4,2880+3,5692+2,8173)e^{-4}=3,9843e^{-3}.
\end{equation*}

Коэффициент $\eta_M$ учитывающий сжимаемость потока, приводит к снижению коэффициента трения пластинки определяется согласно \cite{bib:vassiljev}, принимается $\eta_M = 0,9470$
\end{document}
```

The mutavel package can be download from this link: https://github.com/protsenkovi/latex-ssau-gost-style/blob/master/mutavel.sty

Comment: What is `\bar_`  supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you. Its a bar above the character "x" with subindex t in the case of the row 1 column 2 in the table.

Comment: So you want `$\bar{x}_t`?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a subscript “t” to “x with bar”, the syntax is

```
\bar{x}_t
```

Also `\bar` should never be followed by `_` and math should be properly segregated in `$`.

In the code below there are also other suggestions to improve the typesetting. In particular using `siunitx` and its `\num` and `\SI` commands, along with table features in order to ensure uniform typesetting of numbers and units.

For instance, if you want 2,8173e−4 instead of 2,8173 × 10<sup>−4</sup> you just pass the

```
output-exponent-marker=\mathrm{e}
```

option to `\sisetup` (commented in the code below). Never leave a blank line before a math display.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} % <---- these are needed

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
%  output-exponent-marker=\mathrm{e},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\caption{Коэффициента профильного сопротивления каждого участка крыла}
\label{tab:c_f_at_diff_positions_l/2}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c *{5}{S[table-format=1.4]}@{}}
\toprule
№ & {$\bar{x}_t$} & {Re} & {$\eta_C$} & {$C_F$} & {$2C_F\bar{S}$} \\
участки & & {\num{e7}} & & {\num{e-3}} & {\num{e-4}} \\
\midrule
1 & 0,0756 & 4,4683 & 1,3807 & 2,3886 & 2,8173 \\
2 & 0,0868 & 5,8915 & 1,3768 & 2,4376 & 7,2592 \\
3 & 0,1018 & 3,3214 & 1,3719 & 2,4956 & 6,3388 \\
4 & 0,1148 & 2,9435 & 1,3694 & 2,3388 & 4,9115 \\
5 & 0,1461 & 2,3137 & 1,3636 & 2,3676 & 5,6728 \\
6 & 0,1666 & 2,0286 & 1,3598 & 2,3767 & 4,9863 \\
7 & 0,1938 & 1,7436 & 1,3547 & 2,3796 & 4,2880 \\
8 & 0,2317 & 1,4585 & 1,3399 & 2,3700 & 3,5692 \\
9 & 0,2897 & 1,1668 & 1,3148 & 2,3322 & 2,8173 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Суммарный коэффициент трения крыла определится по формуле:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sum_c_f_wing}
  C_\textup{xa F кр}=2C_\textup{F кр}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (2C_\textup{F j}\bar{S}_j),
\end{equation}
т.о. 
\begin{align*}
C_\textup{xa F кр}
&= 2C_\textup{F кр}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (2C_\textup{F j}\bar{S}_j) \\
&= \num{2,8173}+\num{7,2592}+\num{6,3388}+\num{4,9115}+\num{5,6728} \\
&\qquad+ \num{4,9863}+\num{4,2880}+\num{3,5692}+\num{2,8173e-4} \\
&= \num{3,9843e-3}.
\end{align*}

Коэффициент $\eta_M$ учитывающий сжимаемость потока, приводит к снижению 
коэффициента трения пластинки определяется согласно \cite{bib:vassiljev}, 
принимается $\eta_M = \num{0,9470}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]